# How to show legend for only a specific subset of lines in the "plot" in R?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have 29 curves (for different countries I chose randomly) in the plot, drawn by "plot" function. I can not use ggplot since they are functional data curves and the method uses "plot". I only want to give the legend for the top 5 of the curves. I managed to find the name of the top 5 curves and put them in a legend but the colors of the plot and the legend do not match. What am I missing?

```
plot(fdobj)
title("Functional Curves of Countries")
legend("topleft", y.intersp=0.3,pt.cex=3,pch=20,legend=a, col=seq_along(1:5))
```

Here, fdobj is the functional object which I am plotting. The plot is:
[plot with wrong legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJu6K.png)

The legend and the colors on the plot do not match. Qatar is black, but Spain should not be red but light blue.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df))

Comment: You can probably specify the colours used by ```plot``` using ```plot(...,col=1:29)``` (or whatever), and then specify the same set of colours to ```legend```.  This would give you the chance to choose the subset that you want (using ```[1:5]``` for the first 5, for instance).

Comment: Thank you @DominicvanEssen! How didn't I think that? It solved my problem after I defined a big palette by palette(rainbow(29,s=0.5)).